# reload data from detailview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

in my TableView i use

```
    UserSelect *detailViewController = [[UserSelect alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserSelect" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.title=@"Marca Teste";      
    [detailViewController.view setTag:1];       
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
```

i want after selection in detailViewController(UserSelect) update my TableView how do make?

Another related question

In this code, i set tag to 1, but when my detailView is loaded ,tag always is 0, what`s wrong?

Thanks

edit1

rootViewController .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DataClass.h"


@interface TestTable : UITableViewController {

    IBOutlet UITableView *MyTbl;        
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *MyTbl;

@end
```

and m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *back=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"MENU" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(LoadMenu)]autorelease];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=back;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}


-(void) LoadMenu
{
    if (self!=nil) {
        [self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];               
    }
}



- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.MyTbl reloadData];
}
```

Comment: are you selecting data in the `detailViewController` and reloading data in another tableView or the tableView in `detailViewController` ?

Comment: detailView is a UIViewController ,i want reload in rootViewController. Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `viewWillAppear` of the `rootViewController` set

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I had tried this, I get the following error

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary autoresizeArchivedView]

Comment: Is tableView set as a property ? You can also set is as `[self.MytableView reloadData];` Paste your code for rootViewController anyway :)

Comment: set the `[super viewWillAppear]` as the last line in that method. Also, allocate your self.Mytbl in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Legolas (Lord of Rings?)
Doesn`t working in ViewDidLoad put
self.MyTbl=[[UITableView alloc]init];
and in willAppear
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {   
 [self.MyTbl reloadData];
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];  
}

App don`t crash, but data not is reloaded.

Comment: It should reload if you add the data from the other view controller to the array of the tableView populating the tableView of the rootViewController.

Comment: Debugging application, in reload `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` are calling but not `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ..What`s wrong?? thank you Legolas

Comment: Hm. it should because it is a tableViewController. :O